# Suppressing HTML output in SAS

Tags: sas

I'm trying to suppress HTML output and get `PROC PRINT` to output only to CSV, but `ODS HTML Close` doesn't seem to work.

My code is:

```
ODS HTML close;
ODS CSV file="\\..output folder..\filename.csv";
proc print data=test;
run;
ODS CSV close;
ODS HTML;
```

Comment: What version of SAS are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems a bit odd, why resort to ods csv?
SAS has a proc export procedure:

```
proc export data=test outfile="\\..output folder..\filename.csv" dbms=CSV replace;
run;
```

You can further configure it to have a different delimiter, no headers etc.: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000393174.htm

*EDIT*
In reply to your comment: i see two ways around the issues that keep you from trying proc export.

The first approach is setting the validvarname to ANY, which gives you great liberty in choosing variable names. E.g.:

```
options validvarname=ANY;
data test;
    'Column Header Text I Want'n=1; output;
    'Column Header Text I Want'n=5; output;
run;
proc export data=test outfile="\\..output folder..\filename.csv" dbms=CSV replace;
run;
```

Personally, i'm not a fan of the above approach, since i find that it leads to harder-to-read code when you no longer have some naming rules for variables.

A second approach - which i prefer - is to label the variable with the text you want it to have and put the label option on your proc export. E.g.:

```
data test;
    label variable_name='Column Header Text I want';
    variable_name=1; output;
    variable_name=5; output;
run;
proc export data=test outfile="\\..output folder..\filename.csv" dbms=CSV replace LABEL;
run;
```

Note that there is a small distinction in the output: the first approach will not put quotes around your column names while the second approach will do that.

Finally, while doing some extra reading myself, i stumbled across this, which may be of help to you as well: http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Create_a_CSV_file_without_column_names/headers_in_row_1#DATA_NULL_with_a_PUT_statement.2C_all_fields_quoted

Comment: ODS CSV has significantly different functionality than PROC EXPORT.  Among other things, it's a very easy way to get value labels instead of values in the CSV.

Comment: @Joe: When using proc export to export to CSV, the result is a csv with the formatted data (assuming that is what you are referring to with value labels). Just did a test in 9.2 and 9.3 and i got formatted output (e.g. date9 formatted data as a text string)

Comment: Hi Shorack, the main reason I use ODS CSV is because PROC EXPORT can't handle variable names with spaces in them.

Comment: Hi @TwilightSparkle, i've updated my answer to give some pointers on how you can overcome that limitation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm been trying all day and finally got it for me.  What I wanted suppress from the results viewer is just below here (and the end of a macro).  The results I wanted in the results viewer and now called in a separate macro at the end...
Brubumski

```
  ODS HTML close;   * bsk;
  ods results off;  * bsk;
  ods csvall file="&file1";
  proc print data=tr_outds noobs; run;
  ods csvall close; * bsk;
  ods results on;   * bsk;
  ODS HTML;         * bsk;

  %OdsOn1(outds,outds2,tr_outds, file1, file2); * bsk;

%mend process_input_data_10_10;

%macro OdsOn1(outds,outds2,tr_outds, file1, file2); 
  proc freq data=outds;tables Group_nm/missing;run;
  proc freq data=outds2;tables case_id/missing;run;
  proc print data=tr_outds(obs=10) noobs; run;* bsk;

  ods csvall file="&file2";
  proc print data=cases noobs; run;
  ods csvall close; 
%mend OdsOn1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I've found out the problem. The results window will still display HTML output which will really slow the program down as `ODS HTML CLOSE` seems to only affect ouput to a specific file, not the results window.

In order to stop that, I should have used `ODS RESULTS OFF;` instead.

```
ODS RESULTS OFF;
ODS CSV file="\\..output folder..\filename.csv";
proc print data=test;
run;
ODS CSV close;
```

EDIT: It seems that `ODS RESULTS` cannot be turned on and off at will to cause only certain `PROC PRINT` statements to generate outputs. This is really annoying for me, so I'm going with Shorack's `PROC EXPORT` methods.

Comment: This isn't correct.  I regularly use ODS HTML CLOSE; to close the default html output.  Are you sure you aren't talking about the LISTING destination ("Output" tab)?

Comment: I have been having some difficulty using ODS TAGSETS.EXELXP in Enterprise Guide in that it takes a lot longer than in batch, on the same server. (for output that has a pretty high number of variables...not every TAGSET output) I suspected it was due to also writing to the RESULTS window. I just tried it with RESULTS OFF and it did seem to be faster (and it does not have a RESULTS tab).

Comment: Hi Joe. I think the confusion is due to different versions of SAS. Carolina and I appear to be using SAS 9.3 and above. In 9.2 and below, the LISTING destination refers to the "Output" window. In 9.3 and above (I'm using EG), the "Output" window displays a HTML output and LISTING destination is closed by default. In this case, ODS RESULTS OFF appears to be the correct command to disable output window. A longer discussion of this appears here: http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/250-2012.pdf