# How to speed up SAS BY statement which continuously slows down as it runs?

Tags: optimization, sas, mixed-models

I am running many small mixed models in SAS via the `BY` statement, which takes several hours overall. I am also collecting the ODS output to export to a `.csv` file. From the output in the `Log` window I have noticed that the program goes extremely quickly at the beginning, but continuously slows down as it runs. Is there any way this can be sped up? I have considered running it on subsets of my data, but was hoping there was a more elegant solution that would still export a single `.csv` file at the end. Is this possible? Thank you!

My code:

```
ods listing;
ods output  Tests3=Tests3;

proc    MIXED   data=my_data;               
class   by_group    Factor1 Factor2 Factor3;    
model   response    = Factor1|Factor2   /   ddfm=satterth   s;
random  Factor3;
BY  by_group;   
run;    

proc    export  data=Tests3 outfile='.\Tests3.csv'  dbms=csv replace; run;
```

Comment: You don't need the trace.  Do you still need the the printout if you are generating the TESTS3 dataset?

Comment: Thanks! I removed the ods trace statements. By printout do you mean the .csv file? I need that for the next part of my pipeline, but I do not need to see anything in the "Results Viewer" window, if that's what you mean.

Comment: No the actual printed results of the PROC MIXED. You turned on the listing output. If you have any other ODS destinations open, like HTML or PDF, it is trying to print there also.

Comment: Oh, by printout do you mean the "Output" window? I don't need that, either. I have no code that explicitly sends ODS output to other destinations.

Comment: how many BY groups do you have ?

Comment: @Richard I have about 16,000 BY groups, each one with about 100 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to significantly reduce runtime by adding an

```
ODS RESULTS OFF;
```

statement at the beginning, like so:

```
ODS RESULTS OFF;
ods listing;
ods output  Tests3=Tests3;

proc    MIXED   data=my_data;               
class   by_group    Factor1 Factor2 Factor3;    
model   response    = Factor1|Factor2   /   ddfm=satterth   s;
random  Factor3;
BY  by_group;   
run;    

proc    export  data=Tests3 outfile='.\Tests3.csv'  dbms=csv replace; run;
```

This reduced runtime from over four hours to less than 30 minutes, with no noticeable slowdown as it progressed. Apparently, SAS 9.3 and above automatically produces the output in HTML format and saves it to the hard drive unless specifically told not to, and this file can be quite large given it contains a lot of formatting information. Adding to this large and continuously growing file was the cause of the continuous slowdown.

It should be noted that this solution does prevent the "Results Viewer" window from being displayed, but this suits my present purposes just fine. See also

[Suppressing HTML output in SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609615/suppressing-html-output-in-sas) and

https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/250-2012.pdf

Comment: You don't not need to close the HTML destination if you are turning off all ODS output with the ODS RESULTS OFF statement.  That can be important when using using SAS/Studio or Enterprise Guide as it would be hard for the program to re-create the ODS destinations those tools created.

Comment: Thanks @Tom! I removed the `ODS HTML OFF;` statement.